# How can I serve an extensionless file in IIS with a particular content type?

Tags: mime-types, content-type, iis-8

I have a generic resource uploader that create a GUID for a filename, and keeps an in-memory index of the content type and friendly name associated with each GUID.  When the file is accessed at a URL like "folder/GUID", how can I intercept the request, looking up the content type for that GUID in the memory index, and then serve the file with that specific content type?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a BeginRequest handler in Global.asax and intercept the request. 
Alternatively, if you're working in MVC, then you should have a route which maps to your controller/action which is responsible for serving the file. 
Of course, both of these options mean the request is going through the .net pipeline.
You could possibly look at hijacking the mime types via a location tag in web.config too, however I am not sure this will work as there is no extension to map the mime type on.